# How to find the (angular) frequency of (damped) oscillations from an ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have got the solved ODE

$$ y (t) = e^{-3t} \left( c_1 \cos(3t) + c_2 \sin (3t) \right) $$

and I need to find using the ODE the (angular) frequency of (damped) oscillations from this equation. Any suggestions and help is appreciated.

Comment: Can't you tell by looking at the solution? Do you need to go from solution to ODE?

Comment: Yeah I know its an easy question, but still i personally cant tell by looking at the solution, well i dont know how to tell by looking at the solution.

Comment: Look at the inputs of $\cos$ and $\sin$.

Comment: Ok thanks, ill look at the inputs now.